# Console spamming

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I recently started a new project and our team has a small problem. When we open the console it's spammed with "Failed to execute 'detect' as Sheep":

[image]

We are running 1.12.2.
We also have `testfor` Command Blocks on here:

[image]

And we also need to fix this command: `execute @e ~ ~ ~ detect ~ ~-2 ~ purpur_stairs 0 /tp @e[c=1] ~0.3 ~ ~ -90 10`, because the console is getting very laggy.

Comment: It's a long time since I played 1.12.2, but I'm pretty sure the slash (`/`) in the middle of the `execute` command makes it not work. And I think that the message just means that there exists an entity (sheep) in the world that does not have purpur stairs 2 blocks below it.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, I probably misread, mistyped the last command. It works just fine, I just wanted to add it to there if it is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by adding:

`execute @e[type=Villager] ~ ~ ~ detect ~ ~-2 ~ purpur_stairs 0 /tp @e[c=1] ~0.3 ~ ~ -90 10`.
I added `[type=Villager]` to only try to detect villagers, not all entities.

Comment: Hello! While this is a valid answer, it would be much easier for fellow users to understand what went wrong in the original command if you could add some explanation.